# Simple React useRef example errors

Tags: reactjs

Having such a simple `React` App:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const count = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    count.current = count.current + 1;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        //value={inputValue}
        //onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>Render Count: {count.current}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I'm getting en errors:

> (0 , _react.useState) is not a function (0 , _react.useRef) is not a
> function

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same version of `react` and `react-dom` on your `package.json`?

Comment: @mchowdam Yes, the same both are 16.5.2. Btw I'm running the code on the codesandbox.

Comment: Can you update your question with the sandbox link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks are introduced in 16.8 version. So you can't use `useState`, `useEffect` and any hooks in <16.8 version on react.

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)